# How to install luadoc

Tags: installation, lua

I am trying to install [luadoc](https://github.com/keplerproject/luadoc). 
Running the command make targeting the Makefile does not make any effect. `make: Nothing to be done for '/Users/ernestbofill/.luadoc/Makefile'.`

I have lua installed via macports.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

> make install

Will install (ie. create dirs and copy) luadoc.

Make sure the variables in the Makefile correspond to your needs first:

```
LUADOC_DIR= $(LUA_DIR)/luadoc
DOCLET_DIR= $(LUADOC_DIR)/doclet
HTML_DIR= $(DOCLET_DIR)/html 
TAGLET_DIR= $(LUADOC_DIR)/taglet
STANDARD_DIR= $(TAGLET_DIR)/standard 
LUADOC_REFMAN= doc/refman
```

Answer (score 0):

@fede.evol thanks for your response. Your solution works but I found another option I liked better.

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and luarocks.
Having Homebrew installed do

```
brew install luarocks
luarocks install luadoc
```

and youre good to go. Start using luadoc by typing `luadoc`

Additionally I would recommend to take a look at [LDoc](https://github.com/stevedonovan/LDoc). I tried both and prefer LDoc so far.